# Printing useful output with Log4net in Application_Error and LINQ queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

I'm new to this stuff but what I'm trying to do is filter the log4net log I've bungled into Application_Error by some particular bits of information, such as HTTP_USER_AGENT REQUEST TYPE CONTENT_TYPE HTTP_REFERER.

The code I have so far is:

```
string[] vars = {"IP address", "X-Forwarded-For", "HTTP_USER_AGENT","REQUEST TYPE","CONTENT_TYPE","HTTP_REFERER"};
var param = Request.Params;

var paramEnum = param.GetEnumerator();
while (paramEnum.MoveNext())
{
    foreach (var paramVar in vars.Where(paramVar => paramVar == paramEnum.Current.ToString()))
    {
        Log.Error("\nparam:" + paramVar);
    }
}
```

But it looks ugly and moreover I think I'm not on the right track in terms of a succinct LINQ query, especially using both a while and foreach loop.

I'm new to LINQ as I say and resharper created the LINQ for me - if you feel I'm lacking in certain areas please let me know what I'd need to further my understanding of collections/querying.

Is this the most performant way of doing things, or am I on the wrong track altogether?

Comment: Have you checked `log4net` [layouts and patterns](http://www.beefycode.com/post/log4net-tutorial-pt-4-layouts-and-patterns.aspx)

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) paragraph `Logging Extra Data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to iterate through `vars` instead

```
        foreach (var paramVar in vars)
        {
            var value = Request.Params.Get(paramVar);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Log.Error("\nparam:" + paramVar);
            }
        }
```

or using LINQ

```
        var query = from paramVar in vars
            let value = Request.Params.Get(paramVar)
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
            select paramVar;

        foreach (var paramVar in query)
        {
            Log.Error("\nparam:" + paramVar);
        }
```

Comment: Yep this seems better.. will test it later.